# How to assign first state data to second state in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When i am setting the data from one state to another state. It's saying undefined. Currently i am working on tinder like card swipe functionality with Right and left button click.

I am passing the user id from card to to button. Such as Right swipe and left swipe button.

//Scenario first
If have declared the array of object static, it's works like a charm, then it does not says any error.

////Scenario Second
If i am setting the data dynamically with API to SetState and assigning the state variable array data to another state variable, it says undefined.

I am trying to solve this issue from 3 days, but nothing worked, i am new in React js. Help would be appreciate.

**Here is my code**

```
const AllData= [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'XYZ'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'ABC'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'ABC 2'
    },
     {
      id: 4,
      name: 'ABC 3'
    },
     {
      id: 5,
      name: 'ABC 4'
    }
  ]  //It works if set static array

const [AllData, setAllData] = useState([]); //it does not works

const GetAllUserData = async () =>{
     const bodyParameters ={
   session_id : SessionId
   };

   const {data : {data}} = await axios.post(GETALLUSER_API , bodyParameters);
   setAllData(data); 
}

// Setting current user from all data 
 const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(AllData[0])

console.log(currentUser); // undefined says
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, `AllData` will be added to the state after the `GetAllUserData` is done executing, it is asynchronous function, so `AllData` will be available after some time, you have to update the currentUser you have to do like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (AllData.length) {
    setCurrentUser(AllData[0]);
  }
}, [AllData]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, You saved my day. it's working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

It didn't worked because you may have returned before the setAllData could get called initialize AllData.

Being a api call it take some time to return data.

A good work around for this situation is to put a loader until it get the data and when you eventually receive the data then only render the content on the screen.